# How can I rename Device ID from disk1s5 to disk1s1

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, migration

My brand new MacBook Pro 16" had "Macintosh HD" at disk1s1 and "Macintosh HD - Data" at disk1s2. I didn't realize the USB-C cable that came with it wasn't Thunderbolt 3 so I killed the Migration Assistant and ordered the cable online. When the cable came I reformatted the disk to start over and for the life of me I can't get the Device ID to match what they were out of the box. I've tried starting with a brand new Partition and installing from Disk Recovery, then running Migration Assistant (using the TB3 cable that came today) but now I'm getting Macintosh HD on disk1s5 (was on s1) and Macintosh HD - Data on disk1s1 (was on s2). I realize this doesn't impact the performance in any way but it's bugging me that I can't get it back to the way it came out of the box.

Comment: A quality USB-C cable can also carry Thunderbolt 3 signaling.  What makes you think the cable included with your Mac wasn’t Thunderbolt?

Comment: We might need to see the results of `diskutil list` to piece together your layout.

Answer (score 1):

Device IDs are what the *system* uses to identify the drive.  They often change depending on when and even where they are detected (Internal vs. USB vs Thunderbolt).

For instance, an old hard drive bootable drive might be identified as disk1s2.  Take it out and put it in a USB enclosure, attach it to another Mac and it  suddenly becomes disk3.

This is not something you need to try and manage and trying to make of “match what came out of the box” does nothing except create a massive amount work on your part.

Now the fact that the data partition went from slice 2 (disk1s2) to slice 5 (disk1s5) tells me that you may not have removed/reformatted the drive properly.  However, this is now moving into a new question so issue the command `diskutil apfs list` and post it to a new question as to the structure of your partition layout.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the "disk" portion changes depending on its position in the sequence when mounted, it's only the "s" part (the slice) that I'd like to get back to the way it was.

Comment: @motoservo The partitions (slices) are also managed by the system. As Allan said, post a new question with the result of diskutil list and we can help you to fix things.

Comment: The use of partition and slice is being use incorrectly in this answer and comments.

Answer (score 1):

Hey @motoservo there's [an answer to your question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/440557/457543) kindly provided by @david-anderson if you still need it! P.S. You will likely need to use Terminal to remove old APFS Container without reboot, use [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382224/) by @david-anderson for commands.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/322000)

Answer (score 0):

Shortest possible answer... You can't!

Partial explanation... disk1s5 & disk1s1 are system device IDs, assigned at mount time. If you examine carefully, a given drive might have a different device ID from one boot of your Mac to the next. That's not very human friendly & is one reason why we have volume names. Device IDs for drives apply to logical volumes, not physical drives, so under Catalina & later "Macintosh HD" (or whatever you've renamed it to) will have 2 device IDs, because the System is on a write only partition & everything else on another partition.